# Is it possible to disable SlowMo when Typing?

Tags: playwright

`SlowMo` allows to have an artificial delay while executing the tests so that we can see what's going on, but if I increase it to 1500ms, then it takes ages to **type** something, because each character will be typed after 1500ms.
I wish I could enable the SlowMo only for clicks.

For example:

```
this.Browser = await this.PlaywrightContext.Chromium.LaunchAsync(new BrowserTypeLaunchOptions
        {
            Headless = false,
            SlowMo = 1500,
        });
```

Any idea that might help?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

How about `delay` option on `type()` call?

https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-elementhandle#element-handle-type

Comment: that would not be a clean solution, because I would need to change all references and create a global variable to represent the timeout.
This is an interesting idea though. But I wished that was supported by the framework, like a built-in configuration.